# geom_boxplot + scale_y_log10 bug

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, boxplot, logarithm

I am trying to create some boxplots of lognormal data by group using both geom_boxplot and scale_y_log10. When I checked the plots with the actual values for median and other quartiles I reaized that some of the boxplots were wrongly plotted, i.e. the median and/or other quartiles were not in the right place. After much testing, I realized that when using both geom_boxplot and scale_y_log10 the groups with two values only gave erroneous plots.

Here is the code for a test example:

```
f1 <- function(x) {
log10(mean(10 ^ x))
}

library(ggplot2)

test1 <- data.frame("value" = c(3, 45, 2, 100),
               "field" = c("a", "a", "a", "a"),
               "group" = c("1", "1", "2", "2"))

test2 <- data.frame("value" = c(3, 10, 45, 2, 70, 100),
               "field" = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"),
               "group" = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"))

tapply(test1$value, test1$group, median, na.rm = TRUE)
tapply(test1$value, test1$group, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(test1, aes(x=field, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(~ group) +
geom_hline(yintercept = c(24, 51), colour="blue", linetype=2) +
geom_hline(yintercept = c(24, 51), colour="red", linetype=2) +
scale_y_log10() +
stat_summary(fun.y=f1, geom="point", shape=1, size=3, color="red", 
fill="red") +
theme(legend.position="none") +
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3")

tapply(test2$value, test2$group, median, na.rm = TRUE)
tapply(test2$value, test2$group, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(test2, aes(x=field, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(~ group)+
geom_hline(yintercept = c(10, 70), colour="blue", linetype=2) + 
geom_hline(yintercept = c(19.3, 57.3), colour="red", linetype=2) +
scale_y_log10() +
stat_summary(fun.y=f1, geom="point", shape=1, size=3, color="red", 
fill="red") +
theme(legend.position="none") +
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3")
```

As you can see if you run the examples above, test1 (with two values per group) gives boxplots with wrong medians while test2 (with three values per group) gives the correct boxplots.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Hmm, I think this is related to the log of the median vs the median of the log-transformed variable for an even vector and not about ggplot2. Take a look at `median(log10(c(3, 45)))`.  If you back-transform, `10^median(log10(c(3, 45)))`, you get the same value as your plot shows.  Since the log transformation is monotone, if you have three (or some other odd number) of unique values the median and back-transformed median of the logs happen to be the same thing.

Comment: Wow, I think @aosmith is right but I understood the problem better by using the following exemples instead `log10(median(c(2, 100))) median(log10(c(2, 100))) log10(median(c(2, 70, 100))) median(log10(c(2, 70, 100))) log10(median(c(2, 15, 70, 100))) median(log10(c(2, 15, 70, 100))) log10(median(c(2, 15, 30, 70, 100))) median(log10(c(2, 15, 30, 70, 100)))` The median of log-transformed even data gives a slightly lower value for the median. However, how could this mathematical conundrum be solved for ggplot?